# Best practice for ordering values in an ActiveRecord database by a 'given value' of string in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, sorting, database-design

I'm sure this is a common issue when working with databases, but I'm trying to set up an ActiveRecord database in Rails (although I think this would apply to most database systems), so that I can order my rows based on a value I assign to certain strings.

For example, I'd like to order items based on

```
Common
Less Common
Moderate
Rare
None
```

I can think of a few ways to do it, but each one ends up seeming a little messy. I was hoping that this was a common enough issue that there was an already established best-practice for going about this.

Comment: How do you plan on assigning a value to the strings?

Comment: For example: 'Common' might be 5, 'Less Common' 4... None '0' so that when I sort, Common will be at the top and None will be at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you need [enum](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html):

```
enum status: [:none, :rare, :moderate, :less_common, :common]
```

After that you will have some methods like `item.none?`, `item.status #=> none` etc.
For using enum you should create `integer` field in your table, and each status will be saved as integer `none -> 0`, `rare -> 1` etc. Also you could explicitly map the relation between attribute and database integer.

For sorting by status in this case you could just write:

```
YourModel.all.order(:status)
```